# Confusing example of Private V.S. Public method in book <Javascript Patterns>?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, private-methods, public-method

I've been reading Javascript Patterns by Stefanov recently. And I found this example confusing to me here:

> Another case of using a convention to mimic functionality is the private members >con- vention. Although you can implement true privacy in JavaScript, sometimes >evelopers find it easier to just use an underscore prefix to denote a private >method or property. Consider the following example:
>
> var person = {
>
> getName: function () {
>
> return this._getFirst() + ' ' + this._getLast(); },
>
> _getFirst: function () {
>
> // ... },
>
> _getLast: function () {
>
> // ... }
>
> };
>
> In this example getName() is meant to be a public method, part of the stable API,
>
> whereas _getFirst() and _getLast() are meant to be private.

As I understand it, either a method is private or public is defined by the way it was written. For example, if we are talking about a constructor function, then, "this.getFirst() = function(){ ... } " would be a public method where as "var getFirst=function(){...}" would be private.

The example in the book is not a constructor function, tho. And I do believe one can't simply use an underscore to make a method public or private. How, then, shall we make private or public method in an object declared in the way as the example above?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have *really* private variables / methods. The pattern (underscoring) is just **coding convention**. See [MDN: Private properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties#Using_Prefixes). It reads

> The above technique (underscoring) is simple and clearly expresses intent. However,
>   the use of an underscore prefix is just a coding convention and is not
>   enforced by the language: there is nothing to prevent a user from
>   directly accessing a property that is supposed to be private.

Meanwhile, you cannot use `var getFirst=function(){...}` inside `Object literal {...}` construction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex. This clears my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to say that getName(); is an accessor within the same class as the private data member functions.

Comment: An accessor function is created to access the private members without mutating/altering the values.